# Are there any English equivalents to Chinese proverb"throwing a brick to attract jade"?

Tags: proverbs

In Chinese, "throwing a brick to attract jade" means

> I offer a humble remark, please give us your valued opinion.

See [here](https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?popup=1&wdqchid=%E6%8A%9B%E7%A0%96%E5%BC%95%E7%8E%89&wdrst=0) for the full explanation. Are there any English equivalents to this?

In Chinese, "throwing a brick to attract jade" is not limited to the remarks and opinions. Sometimes people say "throwing a brick to attract jade" to mean "I want to do A to encourage more people to do A and do better in A".

Comment: People will often say, “I’m just throwing this out there to get the conversation started.”

Comment: On online forums, you can indicate that you are not on a par with the people you are joining in with by saying "just a question from the [peanut gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_gallery)" or "just a question from the cheap seats". It implies you aren't planning to get deeply involved in the discussion, but would appreciate an answer. Your second usage sounds a bit like "[priming the pump](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prime+the+pump)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not fully sure I understand the Chinese proverb, but "I want to do A to encourage more people to do A and do better in A" leads me to the English phrase

```
Let me get the ball rolling
```

which roughly means "let me make a feeble or modest effort to encourage other people to participate in a bigger way."